# How to use CSS for NatTables

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, nattable

How can I style a NatTable using CSS?

[This page](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_140.php) shows a snippet that should explain how to use CSS for Nattables.

> To create a CSS style definition, the general selector NatTable can be used. Additionally a class or id based selector can be used. For example you can create a class based style definition

```
.basic {
    cell-background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
}
```

> And then configure that class for a NatTable instance via setData().

```
natTable.setData(CSSSWTConstants.CSS_CLASS_NAME_KEY, "basic");
```

But it's unclear how to tell the NatTable (or eclipse) where to look for that CSS file.

Comment: That uses the CSS file that the Eclipse RCP is using.  That is specified in the properties of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point defining the RCP

Answer (score 0):

NatTable CSS styling is based on Eclipse 4 CSS styling. For details on Eclipse 4 CSS styling have a look at corresponding tutorials like

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/CSS